# L2TP VPN Server on Raspberry Pi

Tags: vpn, l2tp

I setup a L2TP VPN server on my Raspberry PI. When I tried to connect to it from my iPhone, I got the following error in the /var/log/auth.log file:

> Jan 3 10:53:08 raspberrypi pluto[4116]: ERROR: asynchronous network error report on eth0 (sport=4500) for message to 172.56.31.191 port 46424, complainant 172.56.31.191: Connection refused [errno 111, origin ICMP type 3 code 3 (not authenticated)]

What does this mean, and how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Someone had a [similar question](https://lists.openswan.org/pipermail/users/2008-September/015358.html) on the openswan mailing list several years ago.  Good luck; I found setting up L2TP w/ IPSec much harder than openvpn.

Comment: Also, the latest `strongswan` version for Raspbian 8 is 5.2.1.  `pluto` was [removed](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/Pluto) in 5.0.0, and `charon` handles IKEv1 now.  You might want to set up a newer version of strongswan before proceeding.

Comment: I never setup strongswan I am using openswan. Should i use strongswan instead? Is there a big difference in the configurations?

Answer (score -1):

That inbound port number (46424) is the problem.

Change your left port to 17/%any instead of 17/1701.

Make the change in the `/etc/ipsec.conf` file. Value is the `leftprotoport`.

Comment: Sorry that was a bit vague. Make the change in the /etc/ipsec.conf file. Value is the leftprotoport.

Comment: Please edit your answer and explain it properly do not confuse users, be clear